# Converting from Content-type/html to Json in axios request Javascript

Tags: javascript, axios

I am getting response from API using axios in Javascript. However, the problem i am facing is that response is  coming as content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, I cannot parse the response since it is not JSON.  Has anyone faced this problem earlier, i will say thank you if you guys help, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Accept: application/json` in your request headers. Something like

```
axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
    }
}
```

It also depends on your back-end. If your back-end doesn't support JSON response, you can't get JSON.